# What is the probability of winning a bet on 30 of the 37 pockets at a roulette table?

Tags: probability, gambling

At a roulette table, there is a wheel containing 37 possible pockets a ball can land on (each are marked 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. through to 36) and it is equally likely the ball could land on any of these spots.

If I were to say that there is a (roughly) 81% chance that the ball will fall on one of the numbers between 4 to 33 would I be correct? And, what is the chance it will not land on any of these numbers (what is the chance it will land on 0, 1, 2, 3, 34, 35, and 36?).

**In a possibly less confusing way of saying this, would it be correct to equate these probabilities to 30/37 and 7/37?**

*Also, this is not a homework assignment or anything like that. I was thinking of how I could come up with a good strategy for roulette that would minimize losses and maximize profits. Gambler, yes. Cheater, no.

[Picture of roulette table for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGfKa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the correct interpretation. Since in roulette, all of the outcomes are [mutually exclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity) (the ball has to land on a single value, it can't land in multiple spaces at the same time), you can just add up the probabilities associated with each number.

So, $P(0 \text{ or } 1) = P(0) + P(1)$, and $P(0 \text{ or } 1 \text{ or } 2) = P(0) + P(1) + P(2)$, etc.

Since the probabilities for each space are the same, that is, $P(0) = P(1) = P(2) = ... = P(36) = \frac{1}{37}$, you can just multiply by the number of spaces you're looking at:

$$P(0 \text{ or } 1) = P(0) + P(1) = \frac{1}{37} + \frac{1}{37} = \frac{2}{37}$$

$$P(0 \text{ or } 1 \text{ or } 2) = P(0) + P(1) + P(2) = \frac{1}{37} + \frac{1}{37} + \frac{1}{37} = \frac{3}{37}$$

Generally, if you want to know the probability that the roulette ball lands on one of $n$ spaces, it's $n\cdot \frac{1}{37} = \frac{n}{37}$. Plug in $n = 1$, and that's the probability for any one space, and plug in $n = 37$, and that's the probability it lands anywhere on the roulette wheel.

In your question, you're asking for the probability of $n = 30$ (there are 30 spaces between 4 and 33, inclusive), so that's $\frac{30}{37} \approx 81\%$.

Note, many roulette tables have 38 spaces, with $00$ as an option also. In that case, the probabilities for each space are $\frac{1}{38}$, and the probability of landing in 1 of $n$ spaces is $\frac{n}{38}$.

---

To calculate probabilities of specific strings, you can just multiply the probabilities for each individual roll, because rolls of the roulette wheel are [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) of each other (the result of one spin doesn't affect what happens on the next spin).

So, if you have bets placed on $n$ spaces, you have the probability of winning is $\frac{n}{37}$, and the probability of losing is $\frac{37-n}{37}$ for each spin.

Then, if you want to know the probability of winning two spins in a row, that would be $\frac{n}{37}\cdot \frac{n}{37} = \left(\frac{n}{37}\right)^2$. For winning three spins in a row, it's $\frac{n}{37}\cdot \frac{n}{37}\cdot \frac{n}{37} = \left(\frac{n}{37}\right)^3$. In general, the probability of winning $p$ in a row is $\left(\frac{n}{37}\right)^p$. Similarly, the probability of losing $q$ spins in a row is $\left(\frac{37-n}{37}\right)^q$.

This type of probability distribution is called a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) in case you'd like to read more about it.

Comment: Thank you for providing the formula! I'm horrible at math so this made it much easier to understand :)

I do have another question, related, though. How would I calculate the probability of a losing streak, where there's still a 7/37 chance to lose? I'm aware that with a coinflip, where you have only 2 outcomes, you can just multiply the probability to itself over and over, but does that also work in this scenario where there are 37 different pockets?

Comment: Just added a bit more on streaks, your intuition about it being similar to coin flips is right. That's because one spin of a roulette wheel is independent of another, in the same way that one flip of a coin is independent of another (and the same thing holds for rolling dice). Hope this helps!